# Oracle database design to store multiple properties of an entity and to maintain its historical changes

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need a database design to maintain the entity and its properties and also to store the data changes of the property values

**Entity:** Any object for example car

**Properties:** Color, Engine type, Height, Width

**Example:** I created a main table with obj_id and obj_name. Properties table with prop_id and prop_name

```
Create table object (obj_id number, obj_name varchar2, created_date, created_by,last_updated_by,start_date,end_date);

insert into object values(1,'Car');

create table obj_prop (prop_id number, prop_name varchar2, created_date, created_by,last_updated_by,start_date,end_date);

insert into obj_prop values (1,'Color');

insert into obj_prop values (2,'Engine_type');

insert into obj_prop values (3,'Height');

insert into obj_prop values (4,'width');

create table obj_prop_assoc (assoc_id number,obj_id number,prop_id number, prop_value varchar2, created_date, created_by,last_updated_by,start_date,end_date);

insert into obj_prop_assoc values (1,1,1,'White');

insert into obj_prop_assoc values (2,1,2,'Diesel');

insert into obj_prop_assoc values (3,1,3,'250cm');

insert into obj_prop_assoc values (4,1,4,'500cm');
```

So, If any object/property has to be added I can add in above tables.

**Question** Is this is the best design to follow? How can I apply constraints on property values?

**Updated** If I have another table to store different colors

Create table colors(color_id,color_name)

insert into colors(1,'Violet');

insert into colors(2,'Indigo');

insert into colors(3,'Blue');

insert into colors(4,'Green');

insert into colors(5,'Yellow');

insert into colors(6,'Orange');

insert into colors(7,'Red');

Now I want to apply constraint on obj_prop_assoc table prop_name column to have one of the values from the colors table for Color property (Foreign Key Constraint) . How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Master table** : **object** and **obj_prop**. 
*You can apply primary key constraint on ID column of your master table.*

**Transactional table** : **obj_prop_assoc** is your 
*you can apply Foreign key constraint on obj_id & prop_id.
You can also apply Composite Primary key constraint on assoc_id,obj_id & prop_id together.*

Comment: Avi, Please check the updated section in my question

Answer (score 0):

Your DB design looks ok. The only thing to maintain the data Integrity is to bind all the tables with proper Integrity constraints. I would suggest to create PK and FK as mentioned below. Hope this helps.

```
Object table -->Object_id (Generated by Sequence) --> Primary Key --> Unique Index

Obect_Property table -> prop_id (Generated by Sequence) --> Primary Key --> Unique Index

obj_prop_assoc table --> assoc_id (Generated by Sequence ) -->Primary Key --> Unique Index
             Foreign_key on Obj_id Refernecing Object table (obj_id)
             Foreign key on prop_id Referencing obj_prop table(prop_id)
```

Comment: Avrajit, Please check the updated section in my question